# Is (Q,+) a free object in category of groups?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to show that $(\Bbb Q ,+ )$ is not a free object in category of groups... but I am having trouble with .i know i should show that there is no homomorphism Q-->S3 ( for example s_3) .thus for any set X , function i:X--->Q and function $f$:X$S_3$  whit f(x1 )=\not (1) , there is no homomorphism f*: $\Bbb Q$ $\Bbb S_3$ with F*i = f .for this Let $f$ : Z -->  $S_3$ be a homomorphism. Since Z is cyclic, $f$(Z) must be cyclic  Thus $f$(Z) not =$ S_3$ since $S_3$ is noncyclic. There are no homomorphisms from $Z$
onto $S_3$. is it right and enough to proof?

Comment: Well, what _is_ your definition of free object?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X$ is a (non empty) free generating set for $\mathbb{Q}$ and that $x\in X$. Define a map $f\colon X\to\mathbb{Z}$ by $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all other elements of $X$ (if there are any).

Then this should lift to a non zero homomorphism $g\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$. Can you tell what are the homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: is there homomorphism from $Q$ to $Z$ ? because z is cyclic but Q is not

Comment: @safamanesh If $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism and we suppose $f(x)=n\ne 0$, then $f(x/2n)=m$ and $2nm=2nf(x/2n)=f(x)=n$: contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose there were a basis. It clearly must be larger than one element (why?) but suppose it has two elements $\frac ab$ and $\frac pq$ and consider a natural homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For your question :

There is only a trivial group homomorphism  from  $\mathbb{Q}$ to ${S_3}$. If  $\mathbb{Q}$ were free on given any non-empty X. Then the group homomorphism $f:X\longrightarrow S_3$ must be trivial one. So, $\mathbb{Q}$ does not satisfy the universal property of the definition of free object in the group category.

If there were a group homomorphism $\varphi:$ $\mathbb{Q}$ $\longrightarrow$ ${S_3}$ such that $\varphi(p)≠e\in S_3$ for some rational p. Then $|\varphi(p)|=2,3$

\begin{multline}
Case1) : 
\end{multline}

$|\varphi(p)|=2$ , consider the element $\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})\in S_3$. Then $|\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})|=1,2,3$

(a) : $|\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})|=1$, then $\varphi(p)=(\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2}))^2=e^2=e,$ ,a contradiction

(b) :$|\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})|=2$,then $\varphi(p)=(\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2}))^2=e,$ a contradiction.

(c) : $|\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})|=3$,then $\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2})=(\varphi(\dfrac{p}{2}))^4=(\varphi(p))^2=e,$ a contradiction.

Whence,the other case will yield contradictions in such a manner.Therefore just only a trivial group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $S_3$ .